# Get current node url in a custom block

Tags: nodes, blocks, routes, navigation

I'm trying to embed Discourse comments in Drupal, so I'm tryinig tu use this code snippet in a custom block :

```
<div id='discourse-comments'></div>
<meta name='discourse-username' content='DISCOURSE_USERNAME'>

<script type="text/javascript">
  DiscourseEmbed = {
    discourseUrl: 'https://myforum.com/',
    discourseEmbedUrl: 'EMBED_URL',
    // className: 'CLASS_NAME',
  };

  (function() {
    var d = document.createElement('script'); d.type = 'text/javascript'; d.async = true;
    d.src = DiscourseEmbed.discourseUrl + 'javascripts/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(d);
  })();
</script>
```

However, I can't find a way to get the current node URL to replace `'EMBED_URL'`.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Edit : Using twig doesn't seem to work, according to the browser console.

```
  DiscourseEmbed = {
    discourseUrl: 'https://forums.sega-mag.com/',
    discourseEmbedUrl: '{{ url('<current>') }}',
    // className: 'CLASS_NAME',
  };
  (function() {
    var d = document.createElement('script'); d.type = 'text/javascript'; d.async = true;
    d.src = DiscourseEmbed.discourseUrl + 'javascripts/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(d);
  })();
```

Comment: Use the duplicate questions answers to preprocess the current URL into a custom variable.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do it with Twig, but it doesn't seem to work in custom blocks.

Since I'm not a developer I'm trying to find a solution out-of-the-box, I don't know any JS or php nor how to use custom variables.

Besides, even when I try with a specific url for the sake of testing, I need to reload the page once to make it work, which is not the behaviour I'm looking for. But it's a different matter I guess.

Comment: Since you are working in Javascript, is this what you are looking for? https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-the-current-url-with-javascript/

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I was stuck in searching for a pure drupal answer.